# Select span in every second td which doesn't have anchor around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following structure of table:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <a>
        <span>
              some content
        </span>
    </a>
</td>
<!-- td having straight span -->
<td>
    <span>
              some other content
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to select `span` in every second td doesn't have anchor around it. I have tried creating selector below but its not correct. As `not(a)` is not a correct way to use this selector.

```
table td:nth-child(2) not(a) span
```

It would be better if there is a `CSS` only solution otherwise `JS` is okay. Let me know if there is any improvement required in the question.

Comment: Are the `<span>` elements always in those two states (wrapped in an `<a>` element or unwrapped, *never* wrapped any other parent element, such as `<b>`, `<i>`, `<q>` etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the direct descendent selector:

```
table td:nth-child(2) > span
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0eahcaw9/)

P.S. Note that you didn't close your `<span>` elements correctly (missing `>`).